# Intermediate Value Theorem for Integral

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

> If $n>0, \quad n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sqrt{n \pi} \leq c \leq \sqrt{(n+1)\pi}$, then prove that: $$\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}}\sin^2(x)\mathrm{dx}=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{c}$$ $c$ means there exists a value between $\sqrt{n\pi}$ and $\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}$ c came from Intermediate Value Theorem for Integral.

I tried to apply:

$$\dfrac{1}{b-a}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{dx}=f(c)$$
And it looked like this:

$$\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}-\sqrt{n\pi})}\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}}\sin^2(x)\mathrm{dx}=f(c)$$

I didn't make it. I also tried to particate it, for applying this:

$$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\mathrm{dx}=f(c)\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\mathrm{dx}$$

I said that let $\sin(x)=f(x)=g(x)$ so we get

$$\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}}\sin^2(x)\mathrm{d}x=\sin(c)\displaystyle\int_{\sqrt{n\pi}}^{\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x \\
=\sin(c)\left(-\displaystyle \cos \Big|_\sqrt{n\pi}^\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}\right)$$

And then I didn't do anything. Any help or hint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\sin^{2}(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}$

Comment: I tried this, but I will try it again.

Comment: It became so hard to solve again.

Comment: What does the question even *mean*? What is $c$?

Comment: I edit the question sorry.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $c$ means arbitrary value between $\sqrt{n\pi}$ and $\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}$ c came from Intermediate Value Theorem for Integral.

Comment: Then add that to the statement of the problem.

Comment: I, now, completely edited the question.

Comment: You have $n<0$ and it being an natural number?  Do you mean $n>0$?

Comment: I feel like this should read "there exists a $c$", not $c$ being arbitrary..

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm too pensive. So sorry for this interruption, I will edit again.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get such $c$ since if $n$ is odd, the LHS$>0$ and the RHS$<0$.

Comment: I think it is $\sin(x^2)$ not $ \sin^2(x)$.